# Official Source of What Time Zone an XEvent is Logged

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, audit, extended-events

I'm trying to prove that extended events (hence audits as well) are logged in UTC time zone and can't be changed but I can't find an official source. I've searched Microsoft's pages and SQL Server 2012 book but couldn't find anything official regarding this topic, only answers on forums. Could anyone point to an official source?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by can't be changed? Do you mean the value after the event is logged?

Answer (score 5):

I can't find anything official in the documentation either.

But I've previously blogged about this here: [Extended Events Timezones](https://straightforwardsql.com/posts/extended-events-timezones/)

It boils down to an experiment:

1. Running a SQL Server in a different timezone.
2. Looking at the data stored with [sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-xe-file-target-read-file-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Confirming that the data is stored in the UTC format.

Comment: Also, the ring buffer timestamp is an ISO 8601 datetime, like "2022-12-14T10:21:52.413Z". The "Z" indicates UTC.

Comment: I also later found that sys.server_audits system catalog view's create_date and modify_date are described as 'UTC time' [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-server-audits-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).